# How to create SimpleType enumeration with xmlspy in schema?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, xmlspy

I'd like to know how to create a SimpleType that is a enumeration with XMLSpy.

Do you have link or something useful that can help me ?

it's simpletype for country code

```
enumeration  AD ("ANDORRA") 
enumeration  AE ("UNITED ARAB EMIRATES") 
enumeration  AF ("AFGHANISTAN") 
enumeration  AG ("ANTIGUA AND BARBUDA") 
enumeration  AI ("ANGUILLA")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I use,

```
   <xs:simpleType name="countryCodeType">
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:enumeration value=""/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="AA"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="AC"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="AF"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="AG"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="AJ"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="AL"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="AM"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="AN"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="AO"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="AR"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="AS"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="AU"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="AV"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="AY"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="BA"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="BB"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="BC"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="BD"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="BE"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="BF"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="BG"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="BH"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="BK"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="BL"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="BN"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="BO"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="BP"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="BQ"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="BR"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="BT"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="BU"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="BV"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="BX"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="BY"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="CA"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="CB"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="CD"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="CE"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="CF"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="CG"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="CH"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="CI"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="CJ"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="CK"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="CM"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="CN"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="CO"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="CS"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="CT"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="CU"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="CV"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="CW"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="CY"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="DA"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="DJ"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="DO"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="DQ"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="DR"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="EC"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="EG"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="EI"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="EK"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="EN"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="ER"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="ES"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="ET"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="EU"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="EZ"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="FG"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="FI"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="FJ"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="FK"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="FM"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="FO"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="FP"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="FQ"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="FR"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="FS"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="FT"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="GA"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="GB"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="GG"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="GH"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="GI"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="GJ"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="GK"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="GL"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="GM"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="GO"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="GP"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="GR"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="GT"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="GV"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="GY"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="GZ"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="HA"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="HK"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="HM"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="HO"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="HQ"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="HR"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="HU"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="IC"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="ID"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="IM"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="IN"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="IO"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="IP"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="IR"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="IS"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="IT"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="IV"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="IY"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="IZ"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="JA"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="JE"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="JM"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="JN"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="JO"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="JQ"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="JU"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="KE"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="KG"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="KN"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="KQ"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="KR"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="KS"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="KT"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="KU"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="KZ"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="LA"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="LE"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="LG"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="LH"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="LI"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="LO"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="LQ"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="LS"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="LT"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="LU"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="LY"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="MA"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="MB"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="MC"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="MD"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="MF"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="MG"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="MH"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="MI"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="MK"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="ML"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="MN"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="MO"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="MP"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="MR"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="MT"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="MU"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="MV"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="MX"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="MY"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="MZ"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="NC"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="NE"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="NF"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="NG"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="NH"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="NI"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="NL"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="NO"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="NP"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="NR"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="NS"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="NT"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="NU"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="NZ"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="PA"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="PC"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="PE"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="PK"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="PL"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="PM"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="PO"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="PP"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="PU"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="QA"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="RE"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="RM"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="RO"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="RP"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="RS"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="RW"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="SA"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="SB"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="SC"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="SE"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="SF"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="SG"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="SH"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="SI"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="SL"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="SM"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="SN"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="SO"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="SP"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="ST"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="SU"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="SV"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="SW"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="SX"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="SY"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="SZ"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="TC"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="TD"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="TE"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="TH"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="TI"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="TK"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="TL"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="TN"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="TO"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="TP"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="TS"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="TU"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="TV"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="TW"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="TX"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="TZ"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="UG"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="UK"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="UP"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="US"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="UV"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="UY"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="UZ"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="VC"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="VE"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="VI"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="VM"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="VT"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="WA"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="WE"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="WF"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="WI"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="WQ"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="WS"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="WZ"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="YM"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="ZA"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="ZI"/>
            </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the editor on the Schema/WSDL design view:

- Add an element
- Select the element you just added
- In the details panel set

  - Set block = restriction
  - Set type = xs:string
- Then in the facets panel you will have an Enumeration tab where you can add enumerations

[image]